# How would i convert this snippet of code to swift3

Tags: ios, swift

How would I convert this line of code to Swift 3?

```
activeConversation?.insert(MSMessage, localizedChangeDescription: "photo.jpg", completionHandler: { (error: Error?) in ... }
```

Here is the routine:

```
import UIKit 
import Messages

class MessagesViewController: MSMessagesAppViewController { 

    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view. 
    }

    @IBAction func sendMessageButtonPressed() {
        let components = NSURLComponents()
        let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
        layout.caption = "textbook"
        layout.image = UIImage(named: "textbook.jpg")!

        let message = MSMessage()
        message.url = components.url!
        message.layout = layout

        self.activeConversation?.insert(MSMessage, localizedChangeDescription: "photo.jpg", completionHandler: { (error: Error?) in 
            ...
        })

        ...
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Cannot invoke 'insert' with an argument list of type '(MSMessage.Type, localizedChangeDescription: String, completionHandler: (NSError?) -> ())'

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. What type of object is `activeConversation`? Are you using a third party framework like Parse? If so, you need to tell us that.

Comment: no only attempting to write code for message extension

Comment: import UIKit
import Messages

class MessagesViewController: MSMessagesAppViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBAction func sendMessaageButtonPressed() {
        
                let components = NSURLComponents()
        
                let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
                layout.caption = "textbook"
                layout.image = UIImage(named: "textbook.jpg")!

Comment: let message = MSMessage()
                message.url = components.url!
                message.layout = layout

Comment: ty sir i am very new to IOS dev and appreciate the assistance

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. The lack of formatting makes it unreadable. Edit your original question to provide more information. And answer my question: "What class of object is `activeConversation`?"

Comment: @DuncanC - The `activeConversation` is a `MSConversation?` property of the `MSMessagesAppViewController`, all part of the Messages framework.

Comment: The question actually makes some sense now that the OP provided some context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That first parameter should be an instance of a `MSMessage`, not just the type declaration.

But I don't see `insertMessage:localizedChangeDescription:completionHandler:` in the current API. But I do see that the header for `insert(_:completionHandler:)` makes reference to `insertMessage:localizedChangeDescription:completionHandler:`, which makes me suspect that the `localizedChangeDescription` parameter, while perhaps previously part of the API, is no longer.

In comments, you show us your creation of that `MSMessage` instance. I suspect you should just use that, but without any `localizedChangeDescription`:

```
activeConversation?.insert(message) { error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print("error: \(error!)")
        return
    }

    // do whatever you want upon success here
}
```

Comment: thank you very much Rob the issue resolution was spot on.

Comment: self.activeConversation?.insert(message, completionHandler: {(error :Error?) in
        })